# MS SQL variable add value from count in the same statement

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have this Select statement

```
select Id, UserName, from UserTable where Department= @DepartmentInput
```

and a variable to calculate how many users from the department

```
@UserCounter
```

Is there a way to add count(the number of users from the department) into @UserCounter from the select statement should the statement runs in a while loop?

Comment: Provide DBMS version tag. Later versions of sql-server have handy windowing functions .

Answer (score 1):

Presuming sql-server:

```
select Id, UserName, @UserCounter = Count(*) OVER (Partition By Department)
from UserTable 
where Department= @DepartmentInput
```

Otherwise a simple sub-query should work too:

```
select Id, UserName, @UserCounter = (select count(*) from UserTable
                                     where Department= @DepartmentInput)
from UserTable 
where Department= @DepartmentInput
```

The database should be clever enough to optimize that query so that the subquery doesn't need to be avaulated for every (matching) row.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the reply! Is it going to be the same when you do

UserCounter = UserCounter + (Count(*) OVER (Partition By Department)) inside the select statement?